# Minimizing maximum distance for integer case

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, operations-research

I am working with different facility location models giving its single (only one center help a demand zone) and multi-source models (multiple centers can help a demand zone).

My decision variables are
$$
    x_j = \begin{cases}  1 & \text{if a center is located in } j \in J \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
and
$$
    y_{ij} = \begin{cases}  1 & \text{if demand zone } i \in I \text{ is assisted by center } j \in J \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
for the single-source model.

For the multi-source one we have
$y_{ij} \geq 0$ taking integer values and representing the number of people sent to demand zone $i\in I$ from center $j\in J$.

The single-source model is given by
\begin{align}
    \min_{x,y} \quad & \max_{i,j} \{ d_{ij}y_{ij} \} \\ 
    \text{s.a.: } \quad & \sum_j x_j = N \\
                     & \sum_j y_{ij} = 1, \: \forall i  \\
                     & y_{ij} \leq x_j , \: \forall i, j \\
                     & x_j \in \{0,1\}, \: \forall i, j \\
                     & y_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, \: \forall i, j 
\end{align}
So far I have been able to change all the restrictions for the multi-source model.
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_j = N \\
\sum_j y_{ij} = w_i, \quad \forall i  \\
y_{ij} \leq q_jx_j , \quad \forall i, j \\
x_j \in \{0,1\}, \quad \forall i, j \\
y_{ij} \geq 0, \quad \forall i, j 
\end{align}
where $w_i$ is the demand associated to each zone and $q_j$ is the capacity of each center.

However, I am stuck on modifying the objective function so that the distance is not counted several times when sending more than one person.

Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Does your single-source problem also have a capacity for each center?

Answer (score 1):

First note that your capacity constraint $y_{ij}\le q_j x_j$ should instead be $\sum_i y_{ij}\le q_j x_j$ for all $j$.

Now to minimize the maximum distance, introduce constant $M_{ij}=\min(w_i,q_j)$ and binary variable $z_{ij}$, impose constraint $y_{ij}\le M_{ij} z_{ij}$, and minimize $\max_{i,j} \{d_{ij}z_{ij}\}$.